Systemverilog problem of using non-blocking in task
When I use non-blocking in task(like example below), the output_data at 8th clock cycle will be X, how can I fix the problem?
logic [7:0]output_data=0;

initial begin

repeat(8)@(posedge clk);
drive_data(output_data);
repeat(8)@(posedge clk);
$finish();

end

task(output [7:0] out);
output_data<=8'hFF;
endtask

I have tried automatic and ref but erros will occur, I expect it will behave like flip-flop.

to ensure output_data behaves like a flip-flop and avoids X values, use an always_ff block synchronized to the clock... avoid mixing blocking and non-blocking assignments within tasks due to potential simulation race conditions

The code you wrote does not compile. I can assume your forgot to put in the name of the task drive_data. Another problem is it has one argument out which is not referenced inside the task, so it makes no sense.

The task in the post has no name; it can't be called.
This situation should create a compile error.

I expect it will behave like flip-flop.

Using a task in a procedural block (initial) is not the correct way to model a flip flop (ff).  A ff operates in its own thread of execution rather than as one of several statements in a procedural/sequential list of statements.  Synthesis would not recognize that group of sequential statements as a ff.
What you are doing is more like making an assignment in a task at a clock edge.  The task itself is not a good place to model a ff; for the same reason.  A task is a list of sequential statements, not a single statement running in a single thread.  Using a non-blocking (NB) assignment makes it worse, because there is this list of statements to run in order, and now you use a NB whose execution gets scheduled into the future (its not going to execute in the sequence you list in the task).
The task assigns global variable (global meaning not local to the task)  output_data, instead of its local variable out, which works but misses the point of using a task.  The local assignment version needs to be blocking because the task drives its output value before the non-blocking assignment is made.
I named the task, created a clock, printed, and wrapped everything as a testbench so that it could be executed as a simulation.  I included versions of the task done both ways (blocking and NB). Also created a basic Verilog FF model to re-time the output_data signal, as an example of a d FF.
Fixed up post
module tb ();

bit clk;  
  
logic [7:0] output_data;
logic [7:0] output_data1;  
  
logic [7:0] q;  

always #5 clk = !clk;

initial begin
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;
  $monitor("t = %0t, output_data = %h, output_data1 = %h, q = %h",$time,output_data,output_data1,q);  
  //
  repeat(8)@(posedge clk);
  drive_data(output_data);
  drive_data1(output_data1);
  repeat(8)@(posedge clk);
  $finish();
end
  
  // task assigns the local out, which gets passed back to the call  
  task drive_data1 (output logic [7:0] out);
    out = 8'hFE;
  endtask
  
  // task assigns the global variable output_data
  task drive_data (output logic [7:0] out);
    output_data <= 8'hFF;
  endtask  
  
  // model a ff, q is a 1 clk delay of output_data
  //
  // always_ff() is the SystemVerilog equivelant of Verilog always() for 
  // modeling a synchronous process.
  // always_ff @(posedge clk)
  always @(posedge clk)
    q <= output_data;
  
endmodule

Produces
xcelium> run
t = 0, output_data = xx, output_data1 = xx, q = xx
t = 75, output_data = ff, output_data1 = fe, q = xx
t = 85, output_data = ff, output_data1 = fe, q = ff
Simulation complete via $finish(1) at time 155 NS + 0
./testbench.sv:22   $finish();

Waves


you use always instead initial:
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset ) begin   |logic here| end 
to behave as a flip flop
